# Prevent direct access to directory in Node & Express app

Tags: node.js, express

In my express app i have a directory called media in /public, and i want to restrict access to it (and it's sub-directories as well), redirect or display a 404.

How i can achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add a middleware before the `static` (so that it precedes the `static`) and there do whatever you want with a route that points to the directory you want to restrict the access to.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of it being public. If you're restricting access then the name should *not* be `public`.

Comment: Francisco Mateo so what can i do in this case? I can move my media stuff outside of public and change upload paths, but then how can i restrict the access to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you defined `public` folder in `express.static` middleware like this:

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

all `public's` content will be public and accessible by url `/filepath/filename`.

The easiest way to restrict access to `media` folder move `media` folder outside `public` folder.

Comment: Thanks, i got it already. Could you please give me a little help on how to do the restriction outside of /public?
And sorry if it may be a stupid question, but i can't find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my own question.

```
app.all('/media/*', (req,res, next) {
    res.status(403).send({
       message: 'Access Forbidden'
    });
    // or whatever
});
app.use('/media',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'media')));
```

Comment: You need a "fat arrow" after (req,res,next) for that to work.