# Prevent the user from accessing the file with url

Tags: javascript, express, url

I have blog site with express and using json files in it.

file directory

[image]

url

[image]

I want to prevent the user from accessing the file with url and redirect to home

I tried to following code but didn't solved:

```js
app.get('/posts/*', function (req, res, next) {
   res.redirect('/')
});
```

Comment: [Search your title please](https://www.google.com/search?q=express+prevent+direct+access+url+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @AbdiKaan can u share some more code of `server` file where u are declaring static routes

Comment: Maybe you can implement some sort of auth mechanism?

Comment: @mplungjan i solved with [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580719/prevent-direct-access-to-directory-in-node-express-app)